# Check whether unit cell forms a "whole piece" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I wish to check whether a square unit cell, when repeated side by side, forms a valid "whole piece" or not. I am sorry that I may not have described it in an accurate way, but I really do not know how to say this using scientific terms. Let me give you two examples, one for "whole piece" and the other for "not whole piece".

`1` represents rubber, and `0` represents air.

**"whole piece"**

```
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
```

**"not whole piece"**

```
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
```

As you can see, in the "whole piece" case, one can find a path (diagonal counted) from top to bottom and left to right, whereas in the "not whole piece", the path is broken. So if you lift the periodic structure up, part of it will fall apart.

How can I do it efficiently in MATLAB? Is there an efficient way? Built-in?

## Update

Actually, even if `bwconncomp()` returns 1, the periodic structure may not be connected. Let's consider this example.

```
A = 
    0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 1 0 0
    1 1 1 0 1 0
    0 0 1 1 1 1
    0 0 1 0 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0 0

>> bwconncomp(A, 4)
>> 1
```

If I show 4 `A` blocks, then it is like

```
A | A
-----
A | A
        0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0 0 0 1 0 0
        0 0 1 1 0 0 | 0 0 1 1 0 0
        1 1 1 0 1  0|1  1 1 0 1 0
        0 0 1 1 1 1 | 0 0 1 1 1 1
        0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 0 0 0
        0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 0 0 0
        -------------------------
        0 0 0 1 0 0 | 0 0 0 1 0 0
        0 0 1 1 0 0 | 0 0 1 1 0 0
        1 1 1 0 1 0 | 1 1 1 0 1 0
        0 0 1 1 1 1 | 0 0 1 1 1 1
        0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 0 0 0
        0 0 1 0 0 0 | 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

So as you can see, the **`1`** on the left side collides with the *`0`* on the right side of another `A`, causing the thing not a "whole piece". (Placed with no space deliberately to make it patent).

Comment: Even in your "not a whole piece" example, I can find a path from left to right and from top to bottom (diagonal counted), so what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term is "**connected**". Equivalently, each piece is called a **connected component**.

Use [`bwconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) (Image Processing Toolbox) to determine the number of connectrd components. Let `A` denote your matrix. Then

```
c = bwconncomp(A,4);
```

returns a structure `c` whose `NumObjects` field indicates how many connected components there are in `A`. The input argument "`4`" is the number of neighbours you want to consider to defin connectedness: either 4 (don't take diagonals into account; that semes to be what you want) or 8 (include diagonals). So, just check if

```
c.NumObjects
```

is `1` ("whole piece") or more than `1` ("not whole piece"). In your examples, the first matrix has 1 connected component and the second has 3.

If you want it in one line:

```
getfield(bwconncomp(A,4),'NumObjects')==1
```

(or use Divakar's suggestion).

Comment: For one-liner lovers - `max(max(bwlabel(A,4)))==1` +1 for the explanation.

Comment: +1 and thanks a lot for the explanation. However, my case is a little bit more complicated here. Even if I have one connected component, the thing may still fall apart when forming a periodic structure. Please kindly see the question update, where I give an example having one connected component, but still falls apart. In addition, is this bwconncomp computationally expensive?

Comment: @Divakar - Nice piece of code.  Luis Mendo - Nice touch on `bwconncomp`.

Comment: @FarticlePilter - `bwconncomp` is quite efficient.  The heart of the algorithm uses Dulmage-Mendelsohn decomposition - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulmage%E2%80%93Mendelsohn_decomposition.  It basically finds strong connected components in a graph as the main driving force for finding components in a binary image that are connected together.

Comment: @rayryeng While just trying to phrase the question, seems that I already got the answer. I can piece 4 `A` blocks together and `bwconncomp` them as a whole, right? If it returns 1, this guarantees no matter how many times `A` repeats, it is always connected.

Comment: @FarticlePilter - Yes, so long as your object can reach the **extremities** of the grid, the object itself is fully connected, and if when you piece them all together, each block can connect to itself, then it should still return 1.

Comment: @rayryeng Oh, I am referring to the follow-up question in the update part of the question. Is my last comment (piecing 4 blocks and `bwconncomp` them as a whole) the solution?

Comment: @FarticlePilter - Yes.

Comment: @rayryeng awesome. tank uuuu~~~

Comment: @FarticlePilter - D'uhhhhh youuu welcum ok? LIKEA SOMEBODY